# Form with Cloned fields and Line totals, Grand Total not complete

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a form with rows, each of which calculates a line total.  These lines are cloned to the number needed by the user.  The grand total updates as lines are populated.

The only issue is if someone adds multiple blank lines before entering data, the grand total does not update until they enter data on the last line.  If too many lines are entered, and the user elects to remove the last line without entering data, the grand total is not populated.  IF after deleting the empty line, they "reenter" the data on the last used line, the grand total does then calculate.  But it just isn't quite right.  What am I missing?

Please see snippet. (edited with working result)

```js
$(document).on("keyup", "[id^='numberunits']", function() { 
        var total=$("[id^='linetotal']");       
        var row = $( this ).attr('id').split('_').slice(1);
        var qty=$("#numberunits_"+ row );
        var price=$("#priceperunit_" + row );       
        var total=isNaN(parseInt(qty.val()* $("#priceperunit_"+row).val())) ? 0 :(qty.val()* $("#priceperunit_"+row).val())
        var roundedTotal = parseFloat(Math.round(total * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
        $("#linetotal_"+row).val(roundedTotal);
        if($("#numberunits_"+ row ).val() !== "" && $("#priceperunit_" + row).val()  !== ""){
            $('#btnAdd_1').removeAttr('disabled');
        }       
        var totalVal = 0;
        $("[id^='linetotal']").each(function(){
           totalVal += parseFloat($(this).val()) ;
        });
        roundedTotalVal =  parseFloat(Math.round(totalVal * 100) / 100).toFixed(2); 
        $("#grandtotal").val(roundedTotalVal);
    });
$(document).on("keyup", "[id^='priceperunit']", function() {        
        var total=$("[id^='linetotal']");
        var row = $( this ).attr('id').split('_').slice(1);
        var qty=$("#numberunits_"+ row );
        var price=$("#priceperunit_" + row );       
        var total=isNaN(parseInt(qty.val()* $("#priceperunit_"+row).val())) ? 0 :(qty.val()* $("#priceperunit_"+row).val())
        var roundedTotal = parseFloat(Math.round(total * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);        
        $("#linetotal_"+row).val(roundedTotal);
        
        if($("#numberunits_"+ row ).val() !== "" && $("#priceperunit_" + row).val()  !== ""){
            $('#btnAdd_1').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        
        var totalVal = 0;
        $("[id^='linetotal']").each(function(){
           totalVal += parseFloat($(this).val()) ;
        });
        roundedTotalVal =  parseFloat(Math.round(totalVal * 100) / 100).toFixed(2); 
        $("#grandtotal").val(roundedTotalVal);  
    });     

// Cloned Section 1 Script
    $('#btnAdd_1').click(function () {
        var num     = $('.clonedInput_1').length, // Checks to see how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                newNum  = new Number(num + 1),      // The numeric ID of the new input field being added, increasing by 1 each time
                phpNum  = new Number(newNum - 1),      // The numeric ID of the new input field being added, increasing by 1 each time          
                newElem = $('#entry' + num).clone().attr('id', 'entry' + newNum).fadeIn('slow'); // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
        
        /*  This is where we manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new, cloned element
            Below are examples of what forms elements you can clone, but not the only ones.
            There are 2 basic structures below: one for an H2, and one for form elements.
            To make more, you can copy the one for form elements and simply update the classes for its label and input.
            Keep in mind that the .val() method is what clears the element when it gets cloned. Radio and checkboxes need .val([]) instead of .val('').
        */
            // numberunits - text
            newElem.find('.label_numberunits').attr('for', 'numberunits_'+ newNum);
            newElem.find('.input_numberunits').attr('id', 'numberunits_'+ newNum).attr('name', 'purchline[' + phpNum + '][numberunits]').val('');

            // priceperunit - text
            newElem.find('.label_priceperunit').attr('for', 'priceperunit_'+ newNum);
            newElem.find('.input_priceperunit').attr('id', 'priceperunit_'+ newNum).attr('name', 'purchline[' + phpNum + '][priceperunit]').val('');
            
            // linetotal - text
            newElem.find('.label_linetotal').attr('for', 'linetotal_'+ newNum);
            newElem.find('.input_linetotal').attr('id', 'linetotal_'+ newNum).attr('name', 'purchline[' + phpNum + '][linetotal]').val('');

        // Insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field and set focus on first field
            $('#entry' + num).after(newElem);
            $('numberunits_'+ newNum).focus();

        // Enable the "remove" button. This only shows once you have a duplicated section.
            $('#btnDel_1').attr('disabled', false);
            $('#btnAdd_1').attr('disabled', true);
        
            $("#add_purchase_lines").parsley().destroy();
            $('.filled').remove()
            $('#add_purchase_lines').parsley();
    });
    $('#btnDel_1').click(function () {
    // Confirmation dialog box. Works on all desktop browsers and iPhone.
        if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to remove this section? This cannot be undone."))
            {
                var num = $('.clonedInput_1').length;
                // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                $('#entry' + num).slideUp('slow', function () {$(this).remove();
                // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
                    if (num -1 === 1)
                $('#btnDel_1').attr('disabled', true);
                // enable the "add" button
                $('#btnAdd_1').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "add section");});
                var totalVal = 0;
                $("[id^='linetotal']").each(function(){
                   totalVal += parseFloat($(this).val()) ;
                });
                totalVal = totalVal - parseFloat($("#linetotal_"+num).val());
                roundedTotalVal =  parseFloat(Math.round(totalVal * 100) / 100).toFixed(2); 
                $("#grandtotal").val(roundedTotalVal);               
                
            }
        return false; // Removes the last section you added
    });
    // Enable the "add" button
    $('#btnAdd_1').attr('disabled', true);
    // Disable the "remove" button
    $('#btnDel_1').attr('disabled', true);
```

```css
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parsley.js/2.9.2/parsley.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<form id="add_purchase_lines" role="form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-parsley-validate>
  <!-- BEGINNING OF CLONED SECTION-->
  <h4 class="">Purchase Detail</h4>
  <div id="entry1" class="clonedInput_1">
    <fieldset>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
          <label class="label_numberunits" for="numberunits_1">Number Units</label>
          <input class="input_numberunits form-control" name="purchline[0][numberunits]" id="numberunits_1" type="number" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
          <label class="label_priceperunit" for="priceperunit_1">Price:</label>
          <input class="input_priceperunit form-control" name="purchline[0][priceperunit]" id="priceperunit_1" type="number" step="0.01" required /><br />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
          <label class="label_linetotal" for="linetotal_1">Total:</label>
          <input class="input_linetotal form-control" name="purchline[0][linetotal]" id="linetotal_1" type="number" step="0.01" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <!-- end #CLONED SECTION -->
  <!-- Buttons for Cloning -->
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <button id="btnAdd_1" name="btnAdd_1" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" disabled>Add Line</button>
    <button id="btnDel_1" name="btnDel_1" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Remove Line</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group offset-sm-8 col-sm-4">
      <label class="label_grandtotal" for="grandtotal">Purchase Total:</label>
      <input class="form-control" name="grandtotal" id="grandtotal" type="number" step="0.01" />
    </div>
  </div>


</form>
```

Comment: Sorry your question is a bit confusing, so your the grand total isn't calculating properly?

Comment: Sorry not to be clearer, it's kind of odd.  The grand total calculates properly.  You have to play with the snippet.  To reconstruct - put data in first line.  Grand total is fine.  Add a line, enter data, total is fine.  Add 3 lines without entering data - grand total quits working.

Comment: Make it so that the previous inputs have to be filled in, in order to add more inputs

Comment: Took me a while, but I did it.  That should have occurred to me, but as I am one of those people who would add a bunch of lines before doing entry, it didn't.  Now I just realized, as my totals change on keyup, deleting a line that has been filled it already leaves me with an incorrect grand total.  I really hate coding sometimes ....

Comment: Thank you for the pointers.  Snippet is updated and fully functional.  Maybe not the best way to do all of it, but it works!